# Woocommerce text instead of the weight of the goods sql

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce

I would like the text "more than 1000 kg" to be displayed instead of the weight when it is greater than 1000 kg

I have this sql:

```
product_weight.meta_value> 1000 THEN REPLACE ('more than 1000kg')
```

But I am doing something wrong because the code is not working

Please help

Regards.

Comment: Show the full query and what is your expected result

Comment: Formatting numbers in to text, such as adding units or replacing values with words, should not be done in your data layer. However you're displaying this data is where you should be applying that transformation.  (SQL won't allow text in a numeric column, the whole column must be the same datatype, which I'm presuming is numeric.)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE product_weight(
meta_value int );

INSERT INTO   product_weight values  (10),(1000),(999),(89898),(20000),(150);

Select 'More than 1000kg' as meta_value_more_1000 
from product_weight 
where meta_value> 1000;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> meta_value_more_1000
> More than 1000kg
> More than 1000kg
> ```